# Github Pages Define global variable for custom date format

Tags: datetime, jekyll, github-pages

I am hosting a website on github pages. I want the date format of the dates printed to be uniform across the website, and I would like to set it in one place so that the change reflects automatically in all other places. Right now, I set it manually as

```
{{ some date variable | date: "%B %d, %Y"}}
```

I would like to define a variable, say `my_date` which will contain the format `date: "%B %d, %Y"` and then whenever I want to print a date I shall write

```
{{ some date variable | my_date }}
```

I am unable to figure out the exact method of execution and syntax for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a variable in `_config.yml` like this:

```
dateFormat: "%B %d, %Y"
```

and the use it across the whole site like this:

```
{{ some date variable | date: site.dateFormat }}
```